# How can I query the data of two subclasses over the parent class? (sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

What I want to do is create 4 interconnected progressive category classes.I don't know if the method I did is correct. Unfortunately I have been reading the document for days. but I haven't made much progress

Over the 'company' class how can I query all data belonging to the 'DepartmentalUnit' class?

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    departments = relationship('Department',cascade="all,delete-orphan", backref='company',lazy='dynamic')

class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    department_name = Column(String)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id',ondelete='CASCADE'))
    departmentalunits = relationship('DepartmentalUnit',cascade="all,delete-orphan", backref='department',lazy='dynamic')

class DepartmentalUnit(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'departmentalunit'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,nullable=False)
    departmental_unit_name = Column(String)

    departments_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id',ondelete='CASCADE'))
    reportcategoryoftheunit = relationship('ReportCategoryOfTheUnit',cascade="all,delete-orphan", backref='reportcategoryoftheunit',lazy='dynamic' )
```